# Not working / with own Strncpy function

Tags: c, string, pointers, strncpy

I'm having probs with an own function that should make str2 copied to str1 based on the amount of characters.

```
char * strncpy_own(char * str1, char * str2, int c)
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < c; i++, str1++, str2++ )
    {
        *str1 = *str2;
    }

    *(str1 + 1) = '\0';

    return str1;
}
```

Please help, When it starts it immediately terminates and says: CLearningsss has stopped working ( my name of the project ).

Comment: You have to make sure that `size of str1 >= strlen(str2) + 1` so that you don't write into garbage memory, and then use `malloc` to allocate memory for `str1`

Comment: "what not to do in C code"

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this in a debugger? Also, please consider posting a [Short, Self-Contained, Compilable Example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Why don't you get the number of chars from `strlen(str2)` instead of using `c`?

Comment: I think this `*(str1 + 1) = '\0';` should be `*(str1) = '\0';` since `str1` will be incremented one extra time.

Comment: `return str1;`  return to the original position probably

Comment: Please ensure your minimal testcase is *compilable* before you show it to us. Go forth and write your *minimal, compilable testcase* which produces the symptoms and provide it to us when you're done. Make sure it has a *main* entry point and is *compilable*. I really can't say this enough... You'd be surprised how many people forget to make their testcases *minimal* and *compilable*. You already have *minimal*, now focus on *compilable*.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
*str1 = '\0';
```

since it has already been incremented.

In a simplified version

```
while (c-- > 0) *str1++ = *str2++;
```

you can easily see that when `c` is `1`, `*str1` gets `*str2` value, and is incremented, thus `str1` is pointing *after* the value that has just been set. Thus using directly `str1` pointer to set the final `0` to indicate the end of the string can be written as

```
while (c-- > 0) *str1++ = *str2++;
*str1 = 0;
```

(actually `'\0'` represents a char value of zero, thus writing directly `0` works as well)

Also, (thanks to @Guillaume_Morin for mentioning that) the function should better return a pointer to the beginning of the result string (str1), and you need to keep a copy of the initial *str1* for that, since it is incremented later on:

```
char * strncpy_own(char * str1, char * str2, int c) {

    char *str1copy = str1;

    while (c-- > 0) *str1++ = *str2++;
    *str1 = 0;

    return str1copy;
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  I'd add that strncpy is supposed to return the original str1.  The code here returns a pointer to the nul character.

Comment: Thanks! How do I try it in a program so I can see that it works? I've been trying with puts(strncpy_own(char *,char *,c)); I've also tried to write printf with both characters and string %c %s it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you allocate the memory for str1 and str2 in advance? You need c + 1 bytes for each string; c + 2 for the mutated string given the bug you have that another answer has pointed out;-)

Comment: No I didn't, I haven't started learning allocating memory and such yet, but I will probably learn that in a few weeks :).

Comment: You need to learn that before your code will work. Google malloc

Comment: Oh okey, ty! The problem is, in my book I'm in chapter 11 and so. And it is about strings. One exercise told me to make an own function for srncpy but next chapter is about malloc how you allocate memory about the heap, free memory I guess and stuff.

Comment: Read Kernighan and Ritchie as well; the C bible

Comment: Oh okey but if I want to keep going on fast with C++ shouldn't I continue finishing this book and then starting  with the C++ book?

Comment: I'd digress if I were you and read K&R and do all the example exercises. That will give you a solid grounding.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *strncpy_my(char *str1, char *str2, size_t size){
    char *ret = str1;
    while(size>0){
        if(*str2=='\0')break;
        *str1++ = *str2++;
        --size;
    }
    while(size>0){
        *str1++ = '\0';
        --size;
    }
    return ret;
}
```